# How to force Sections to be Heading2 H2 in Plastex

Tags: tex4ht, latex2html

Plastex is open source (Python) translator from LaTeX to HTML.

https://github.com/tiarno/plastex

It does a really good job, producing very clean HTML.
For those of use that use LateX for writing from a letter to a 450 page book, it turns out that, through Plastex, LaTeX can be used to easily produce Websites without any knowledge of HTML, etc.

However, when translating a Book `\documentclass{book}` into HTML, Plastex labels Chapter titles and Sections titles, both as `H1`. Subsetions get to be `H2`.

How can I change the behavior of Plastex to make Chapters `H1`, Sections `H2`, and Subsections `H3`?

Comment: Looks like [Sectioning.zpts](https://github.com/tiarno/plastex/blob/master/plasTeX/Renderers/XHTML/Sectioning.zpts) dictates that parts, chapters, and sections all get H1 tags, so that by the time you get to subsubparagraphs, those are at H6. Adjust that file as needed, which may or may not require reinstalling plastex.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I got it to work modifying Sectioning.zpts. Wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Mike, @mike-renfro , I modified Sectioning.zpts to change the headinglevel of sections, etc. down one from h1 to h2. While I was at it, I added "bibliography" together with section at level h2 (I need chapter by chapter bibliography),

```
name: part chapter
<h1 tal:attributes="id self/id" tal:content="self/fullTitle">Morbi metus pede, imperdiet vitae</h1>
<p tal:replace="self"></p>

name: section bibliography
<h2 tal:attributes="id self/id" tal:content="self/fullTitle">Cras dignissim</h2>
<p tal:replace="self"></p>

name: subsection
<h3 tal:attributes="id self/id" tal:content="self/fullTitle">Velit id pharetra</h3>
<p tal:replace="self"></p>

name: subsubsection
<h4 tal:attributes="id self/id" tal:content="self/fullTitle">Donec elementum mauris vel urna</h4>
<p tal:replace="self"></p>

name: paragraph
<h5 tal:attributes="id self/id" tal:content="self/fullTitle">Duis orci</h5>
<p tal:replace="self"></p>

name: subparagraph subsubparagraph
<h6 tal:attributes="id self/id" tal:content="self/fullTitle">Mauris fringilla, metus</h6>
<p tal:replace="self"></p>
```

and thus I had to modify Bibliography.zpts to get h2 on the bibliography heading, as follows:

```
# <h1 tal:content="self/title">Bibliography</h1>
<h2 tal:content="self/title">Bibliography</h2>
```